# "System.StackOverflowException" occurred in HtmlAgilityPack.dll

Tags: c#, asp.net, dll, html-agility-pack

I tried to scrap the page using HtmlAgilityPack.dll but some url get into the function, I got the error and I can't catch it in try-catch block. So can anyone help me out?

Error:
An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in HtmlAgilityPack.dll

```
public void HtmlLoad(string url)
    {
        try
        {
            HttpWebRequest myHttpWebRequest = null;     //Declare an HTTP-specific implementation of the WebRequest class.
            HttpWebResponse myHttpWebResponse = null;   //Declare an HTTP-specific implementation of the WebResponse class
            //Create Request  // 
            myHttpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
            myHttpWebRequest.Method = "GET";
            myHttpWebRequest.ContentType = "text/html; encoding='utf-8'";
            //Get Response
            myHttpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)myHttpWebRequest.GetResponse();

            HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();

            Stream data = myHttpWebResponse.GetResponseStream();//client.OpenRead(url);
            doc.Load(data);
            data.Close();

        }
        catch (Exception ex) { throw ex; }
    }
```

Comment: How many times you have executing `HtmlLoad(string url)` method?

Comment: please don't rethrow exception that way, if you really need to rethrow exception use just throw; otherwise you will lose call stack information

Comment: @M. Nasser Javaid 10 times

Comment: Tell me .Net Framework version.

Comment: Is it loading a particular content or a particular iteration that is causing the overflow?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this clean

```
 public static async Task<int> HtmlLoadAsync(string url/*, bool addUserAgent = false*/)
    {
        try
        {
            var client = new HttpClient();
            //if (addUserAgent)                 OPTIONAL 
            //{
            //    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.UserAgent.ParseAdd(UserAgent);
            //}
            //client.Timeout = TimeOut;
            var response = client.GetStringAsync(url);
            var urlContents = await response;
            var document = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
            document.LoadHtml(urlContents);
            // process document now
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Now call it

```
private async void Process()
{
  await HtmlLoadAsync("http://....");
}
```

Comment: @keerthi You need to add reference `System.Net.Http`

Comment: Can you tell me the version of HtmlAgilityPack.dll?

Comment: HtmlAgilityPack.dll version 1.4.9.0

Comment: How do you calling it? and have you tried it with different URL?

Comment: Some of links the throw the error, otherwise is working good.

Comment: @keerthi - try Wrapping HtmlDocument and HttpClient in using statements to ensure memory is released properly.

Comment: Can you check the content size of those URLs which causing problem? I think their content size is too large that `HtmlAgilityPack` does not support

Comment: How can check the content length?

Comment: You can find the size of `urlContents` field by memory profiler or just get its length as string.

Comment: Generally you can get the idea to see the contents while debugging. Also verify that is there java scripts & css are inline. You can modify to remove these scripts if content size is too large before loading html into HtmlAgiglityDocument.

Comment: what is HtmlAgilityDocument max length? any idea